# can I replace everything after underscore?

Tags: jquery

I have some links that have _2 if they are duplicates, I want to keep the href the same but change the text to remove the _2, sometimes there's an _3 or _4 so I just want to remove from the text everything after the _.

Here is an example of the href's I want to change

```
<li style="display: list-item;" class="menu-item">
        <div><a href="/_webapp_4002837/Dior-Charlize-Theron-2">Charlize-Theron_2</a></div>
      </li>
      <li style="display: list-item;" class="menu-item">
        <div><a href="/_webapp_4002840/Dior-Natalie-Portman">Natalie-Portman</a></div>
      </li>
      <li style="display: list-item;" class="menu-item">
        <div><a href="/_webapp_4002838/Dior-Sharon-Stone-4">Sharon-Stone_4</a></div>
      </li>
```

I have already found a code that replaces the hyphens with space's and this works well, so my code so far is

```
$(".images li").find("a").each(function(i){
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/-/g," "));
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/_/g,""));//removes the _
});
```

Any Ideas? Thanks for replys

Comment: @Rumplin have you read his question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this:

```
$(this).text($(this).text().replace(/_\d+$/, "_"));
```

Comment: I wanted to remove the underscore too but this works well thanks very much - used this $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/_\d+$/, ""));

Comment: ah yes, i thought you want to leave underscore because your question says you want to replace everything *after* underscore :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).text($(this).text().split('_')[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).text($(this).text().replace(/_([0-9])+/, ''));`